# get stdclass object array cat_id value?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to get cat_id ?

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 17
                [res_id] => 10
                [cat_id] => 3
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 18
                [res_id] => 10
                [cat_id] => 4
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 52
                [res_id] => 19
                [cat_id] => 1
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 53
                [res_id] => 19
                [cat_id] => 3
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 54
                [res_id] => 19
                [cat_id] => 4
            )
```

I want `cat_id` from all `stdClass Object` array.

how can i get this ?

Can anyone help me how do I retrieve the value of `cat_id?`
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$Your_array
foreach($Your_array AS $Cat){
   echo $Cat->cat_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). For example, if your source array is `$array`:

```
$result = array_map(function($x){
    return $x->cat_id;
}, $array);

print_r($result);
```

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7G2kW)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
$object = new stdClass;
$object->id= "ID";
$object->res_id = "RES_ID";
$object->cat_id = "CAT_ID";
$array[] = $object;
```

To Access to object attribute:

```
echo $array[0]->cat_id;
```

You can replace `0` with `index` and iterate it in array:

```
for($index=0;$index<count($array);$index++){
    if(isset($array[$index]->cat_id)){
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object properties in PHP are accessed using the `->` syntax. To get the `cat_id` property of each item in the array, you could loop through the array to get each item one by one, and store the `cat_id` property of the objects in a new array, like so:

```
$cat_ids = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    $cat_ids[] = $item->cat_id;
}

print_r($cat_ids);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

If you don't need all the cat_ids, but just the one for a specific object in your original array, you can use

```
$array[2]->cat_id;
```

Which would get the `cat_id` property of the 3rd item in your array.